# Java Spigot, Popultate and block.setType cause StackOverflow

Tags: java, stack-overflow, minecraft

i'm actually developing a little ore remover plugin using `Spigot 1.15 API`.

Here is my problem. when i use `block.setType()` in my populate method (which is called by minecraft generator), it seems to call back the minecraft generator.

This cause a StackOverflowError. See this [log](https://pastebin.com/Syq9u2ak)

My question is, how could i do to stop this callback.

Here are my sources :
Plugin.yml :

```
#####################################
#    General Plugin Informations    #
#####################################

name: Remover

author: me

version: 1.0

api-version: 1.15
prefix: Remover

main: OresRemover.Remover

load: startup
```

Remover Class:

```
package OresRemover;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Remover extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new RemoverListener(), this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
    }
}
```

RemoverListener Class

```
package OresRemover;

import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.event.world.WorldInitEvent;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class RemoverListener implements Listener {

    Logger logger;

    public RemoverListener () {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

    }

    @EventHandler
    public void onWorldInit(WorldInitEvent e) {
        if (e.getWorld().getName().equals("world"))
            e.getWorld().getPopulators().add(new CustomPopulator());
    }
}
```

CustomPopulator Class:

```
package OresRemover;

import org.bukkit.Chunk;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.entity.Entity;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.generator.BlockPopulator;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CustomPopulator extends BlockPopulator {
    Logger logger;

    public CustomPopulator() {
        logger = Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");

    }

    @Override
    public void populate(World world, Random random, Chunk chunk) {
        int X, Y , Z;
        for (X = 0; X < 16; X++)
            for (Z = 0; Z < 16; Z++) {
                for (Y = world.getMaxHeight() - 1; chunk.getBlock(X, Y, Z).getType() == Material.AIR; Y--);
                logger.info("Surface at x:" + X + " y:" + Y + " z:" + Z);
                for (; Y > 0; Y--)
                    if (isOreType(chunk.getBlock(X, Y, Z).getType())) {
                        logger.info("Cave block found at x:" + X + " y:" + Y + " z:" + Z + " and Type is " + chunk.getBlock(X, Y, Z).getType().toString());
                        chunk.getBlock(X, Y, Z).setType(Material.STONE);
                    }

            }
    }

    private List<Material> oreMaterial = Arrays.asList(
            // Ores
            Material.COAL_ORE,
            Material.IRON_ORE,
            Material.LAPIS_ORE,
            Material.REDSTONE_ORE,
            Material.GOLD_ORE,
            Material.DIAMOND_ORE,
            Material.EMERALD_ORE

    );



    private boolean isOreType(Material block) {
        for (Material material : oreMaterial)
            if (block == material)
                return (true);
        return (false);
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciate. Thanks

Comment: https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/blockpopulator-giving-stackoverflowerror-when-setting-blocks.411745/

Answer (score 0):

`Block.setType` by default updates neighboring blocks, which, if happening near a yet unpopulated chunk, causes it to populate as well, and so on. This needs to be turned off with the second boolean parameter: `setType(Material.STONE, false)`.